# @Appstorage is not updating based on my picker selection - SwiftUI - WatchApp

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch

I have a picker that updates an variable bmr.
the picker in not updating the value. I put a test Text on the second screen to see if I can call the new value, its always showing the default.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("ProfileView") var profileView:Bool = false
    @AppStorage("ContentView") var contentView:Bool = false
    @AppStorage("TimerView") var timerView:Bool = false
    @AppStorage("Name") var userName: String?
    @AppStorage("BMR") var bmr: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $bmr, label: Text("Enter your BMR:")) {
                Text("50").tag(50)
                Text("60").tag(60)
                Text("70").tag(70)
                Text("80").tag(80)
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                Text("Save")
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("ProfileView") var profileView:Bool = false
    @AppStorage("ContentView") var contentView:Bool = false
    @AppStorage("TimerView") var timerView:Bool = false
    @AppStorage("Name") var userName: String?
    @AppStorage("BMR") var bmr: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your BMR: \(bmr ?? 50)")
            }
    }
    }
```

I am learning, so I don't know what to really try. I tried binding and unbinding, its not really working.

I tried to store variables and pass through views previously to test if it would update, and it worked fine. But passing info through views doesn't work with my app as I need this data to to be stored even if I exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is `bmr` is an `Int?` while your tags are `Int`. Since they are not the same thing, the selection won't update it. The trick is to cast your tag as an `Int?` like this:

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("ProfileView") var profileView:Bool = false
    @AppStorage("ContentView") var contentView:Bool = false
    @AppStorage("TimerView") var timerView:Bool = false
    @AppStorage("Name") var userName: String?
    @AppStorage("BMR") var bmr: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $bmr, label: Text("Enter your BMR:")) {
                Text("50").tag(50 as Int?)
                Text("60").tag(60 as Int?)
                Text("70").tag(70 as Int?)
                Text("80").tag(80 as Int?)
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                Text("Save")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

The tag and the selection types must EXACTLY match.

Comment: Thank you so much! that's exactly it! Learned something new!